# performSegue:withSender: sender object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

Just wondering about the sender object.

I know that you can access it in the method `prepareForSegue...` but is it available at all in the next `destinationViewController`?

i.e. in the `viewDidLoad` could I access a `segueSender` object or something?

I haven't ever seen this in documentation I just thought it might be useful.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**

I'm not asking how to perform a segue or find a segue or anything like this.

Say I have two view controllers (VCA and VCB).

There is a segue from VCA to VCB with the identifier "segue".

In VCA I run...

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:@"Hello world"];
```

My question is can I access the @"Hello world" string from VCB or is it only available in the `prepareForSegue...` method inside VCA?

i.e. can I access the segue sender object from the destination controller?

Comment: u can use for get view controller object from story board 
UIStoryboard *iPhoneStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
ViewController *firstViewController = [iPhoneStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

Comment: ?? Did you read the question?

Comment: you have to access destination view controller in view did load?

Comment: No, I asked if I could access the `sender` object sent in to the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method in the `destinationViewController`.

Comment: yes u get sender object in prepareForSegue method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Old question but Ill pop in an answer using swift

first you call

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("<#your segue identifier #>", sender: <#your object you wish to access in next viewController #>)
```

in prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! <# your destination vc #>
        dest.<# sentThroughObject #>  = sender
    }
}
```

Then in vc you segue to have a var that will accept the passed through object

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    var <# sentThroughObject #> = AnyObject!()

 //cast <# sentThroughObject #> as! <#your object#> to use
}
```

UPDATE: SWIFT 3

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "<#your segue identifier #>", sender: <#Object you wish to send to next VC#>)


override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destinationController as! <# cast to your destination VC #>
        destination.sentViaSegueObject = sender as? <#your object#> 
    }
```

In destination VC have a property to accept the sent Object

```
 var sentViaSegueObject = <#your object#>?
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the chosen answer is a non-answer @Fogmeister ? There are several correct answers here (as in passing the data to your destination controller). This one I'm commenting on is the most up-to-date and complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get a segue from the storbyoard, and get the `sourceViewController`. Something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStorboard" bundle:nil];
UIStoryboardSegue *mySegue = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mySegue"];
[mySegue sourceViewController];
```

EDIT:
Comments beat me to it. ;)

Comment: OK, but in code in the viewController I can run this line of code... `[self performaSegueWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier" sender:someObject];`. My question is not how to access a segue or how to perform a segue. My question is simply, is `someObject` available in the destinationViewController.

Comment: Well, you could set the senderobject as a property of the destinationViewController (or the source), before the segue is performed. To have a method get the sender of a segue, I think the problem would be that one segue with one identifier, could be performed many times, with different senders, therefore it's hard to identify the right instance of the segue in the destinationViewController, hence hard to get the right sender. Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964487/get-sender-of-segue-in-destination-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass an object from one view controller to the next you may want to do something like this:

In your parent view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Only if you have multiple segues.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NameOfYourSegue"]) {
        // Cast necessary to access properties of the destination view controller.
        [(YourChildViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setObject:theObjectToPass];
    }
}
```

You need to give your segue a name in the storyboard and declare a property for the object to pass in the destination view controller.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I knew about this I just wasn't sure if the sender object was possibly available in the destination view controller.