# How can you utilize sender in the performSegueWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios

I have programmatically initiated a segue with the following method:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginToCategories" sender:object];
```

I was wondering if the new view controller object could access the "object" I inserted in sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the destination view controller to get the sender of a segue, you will need to send a message to the destinationViewController from the `prepareForSegue` method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        MyViewController *destinationViewController = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationViewController.sender = sender;
    }
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964487/get-sender-of-segue-in-destination-view-controller) is highly similar.

Comment: Confused. Why does performSegueWithIdentifier() take a sender if we can't access it?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can access.
add this in your loginToCategories

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourControllerName"]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I add this code to the view controller object that is being segued to?